# What is the support of a basis function?

Tags: terminology

I'm a reading a paper on surface interpolation [1].

However, there is a term that I cannot make sense of and I cannot find it via Google either. The text reads as follows:

> The discrete equations we developed in the section were obtained using nodal basis functions, which have **local support**. This makes the computation of the discrete equations easier (more uniform), and results in a set of sparse equations, which are essential for a massively parallel implementation. An alternative to these nodal basis functions are the hierarchical basis functions developed by Yserentant. In this approach, the usual nodal basis set x is replaced by a hierarchical basis set y. Certain elements of the hierarchical basis set have **larger support** than the nodal basis elements, which allows the relaxation algorithm to converge more quickly when using the hierarchical set.

What does support mean when it comes to basis functions?

Comment: Support of a function generally means the subset of the domain where the function is not zero. IDK what local support means but I think it means the support is a bounded set.. does that help?

Comment: Yes it exactly means that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Properties

Comment: A response would do no harm you know?